# C programming - Sum using Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, sum

```
    int sum(int n)
    {
        if(n==0)
            return n;
        else
            return n+sum(n-1);    /*self call  to function sum() */
    }
```

Can anyone please explain to me how it sums up with the previous value each time it enters the sum(int n) function. I mean, in 'return n+sum(n-1)', how does the 'n+' part gets into the next cycle when sum(n-1) is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The n value doesn't go to the next cycle. The function just keeps on repeating till the n-1 value becomes 0.

When this happens, from your function, you can see that if(n==0) you will return 0, and so it return that value to the previous value for sum(1), which is n + sum(0) ~ 1 + 0.

This repeats till it finally reached the realy sum(n) value.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: It does makes sense but isn't it different from your other comment? I think your other answer makes more sense. Its easier to understand by thinking each step as an expanded form of the function call in the previous step. Thanks a lot for shedding light! :)

Comment: Pardon my slow understanding! After giving it some thought, i find this explanation more apt.

Answer (score 2):

```
n+sum(n-1)
```

Let's say n=4

```
4 + sum(3)
4 + 3 + sum(2)
4 + 3 + 2 + sum(1)
4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + sum(0)
4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 10
```

Comment: Thanks Gopi. But my question is how the 'value' becomes a part of the next loop. After '4 + sum(3)' is encountered, how does '4' gets to the next loop when the sum() function only passes '3' as its argument?

Comment: @optimist You can imagine like the first call which you make to this function wants to return the statement, but that this is possible it has to call the function again and it also wants to return it and so on...

Comment: It doesn't become part of the next cycle. The cycle becomes part of it. I've explained the same on my answer, and this answer by @Gopi is a perfect example of how it works.

Comment: @RJJ Now that was clear! 'The cycle becomes part of it' was what i did not know earlier. Now i can picture how it works. Thanks a lot RJJ.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks Rizier123. I didn't know that. Did it now.